# ¿Cómo calcular la fecha de hoy con la fecha a vencer que esta en la bbdd?

Tags: php, ajax, date, datatable

#Estimados he estado tratando de hacer el calculo de la fecha de hoy con la fecha_vencimiento_revision_tecnica. Quiero que me haga el calculo de cuantos días faltan. Con esta funcion diff hace el calculo. Pero como lo puedo hacer si es un arreglo.

```
 <?php
require("Conexion/revision_tecnica.php");

$todayDate=new DateTime('now');

$sentencia =("SELECT id_revision_tecnica,patente_camion,fecha_revision_tecnica,fecha_vencimiento_revision_tecnica FROM revision_tecnica 
    INNER JOIN tracto on tracto.id_tracto=revision_tecnica.tracto_id_tracto");
   $data = $base->query($sentencia)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

   
    
      $todayDate=new DateTime('now');
$fechas = array();
     foreach($data as $datos) {
   echo   $fechas[]= $datos['fecha_vencimiento_revision_tecnica'].'<br />';
    

    }


echo json_encode( array('data'=>$data) );
?>
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema o error estimado? Pulse en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: Puede crear dos `DateTime`, uno con cada fecha, y luego usar `diff` para saber cuántos días hay entre ambas fechas.

Comment: He añadido una respuesta sobre cómo se haría desde PHP, aunque no queda claro si quieres eso en los resultados de la consulta SQL ¿? Si es así, puedes hacer algo parecido mediante código SQL.

Comment: @A.Cedano y si fuera un array de fechas que proviene de mysql?

Comment: Como dije en otro comentario, puedes traerlo ya calculado en la consulta SQL o puedes hacerlo desde PHP (recorriendo cada fila y creando en cada caso el valor para `$givenDate`). Si lo traes ya hecho mejor, ahora bien, debes aclarar el problema en ese sentido y si lo quieres a nivel de SQL decir de qué tipo es la columna que tiene la fecha.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo voy hacer desde sql mejor es la mejor manera. Asi que voy a trabajar en eso :)

Comment: Si, SQL tiene también formas de calcular intervalos entre fechas. Inténtalo y si tienes algún problema puedes abrir una nueva pregunta al respecto y te ayudaremos.

Comment: @A.Cedano actualice la pregunta

Comment: Si la consulta trae  varias filas y quieres hacerlo en PHP, tienes que implementar lo que he señalado en mi respuesta allí donde vayas a mostrar los datos. Supongamos que vas a mostrar el contenido de `$data` en alguna parte, pues allí debes aplicar el código que te indico en la respuesta, creando por cada fila un `DateTime` para encontrar la diferencia con `$todayDate`. O, si quieres traerlo ya calculado, tienes que escribir una consulta SQL que te haga ese cálculo y te lo traiga ya en una columna con los resultados. Son dos cosas distintas, debes decidirte por una o por otra...

Comment: ... Si te decides por hacerlo en PHP, el código de esta respuesta te serviría, sólo que debes implementarlo allí donde despliegas los datos. Si te decides por traerlo ya calculado (en los resultados de la consulta SQL), es mejor que abras una nueva pregunta, porque es otro tema, y deberías indicar de qué tipo son las columnas en tu base de datos, para saber qué funciones aplicar y qué herramientas usar para hacer el cálculo de la diferencia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías crear dos objetos `DateTime`, uno con cada fecha, y luego usar `diff` para calcular la diferencia entre ambos.

Por ejemplo:

```
/*
    Siempre la fecha de hoy.
    Si trabajas en un contexto de bucle, 
    declara esta variable fuera del bucle
    */

$todayDate=new DateTime('now');
# Fecha dada, que tomarás en el contexto
$givenDate=new DateTime ('2022-07-10');
$mDiff = $todayDate->diff($givenDate);
echo $mDiff->days;
```

**Salida:**

```
87
```

Aquí, `$mDiff` es un objeto del tipo [`DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.dateinterval.php), y puedes usarlo para más cosas, como saber el número de años, meses, horas, minutos, segundos ... y también puedes usarlo con `format()`.